# Update a loop so that if 13 is a number between num1 and num2

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I need to update a loop so that if 13 is a number between num1 and num2 (inclusive), then the loop skips it and continues to push the rest of the numbers to the array.

I am getting the error that I need to push 13 to the array. My updated code:

```
var addToArray = function(num1, num2) {
  var array = [];
  for (var i = num1; i <= num2; i++) {
    if(num1 > 12 && num2 < 14 ){
      continue;
    } 
    array.push(i);
  }
  return array;

};
```

Comment: Can you clean up your code and tell us what's wrong?

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: @Lkoprivica, the braces are all out of line and the phrase `enter code here` shouldn't be in the code above. Also, the if statement `if(sum.length == 0) return sumOfArray;` should have an opening brace after the parens and and a closing brace after sumOfArray. My issue is I don't see where you define num1 and num2. So not sure how to help.

Comment: I don't know why 'enter code here' was there. It should not be. I checked that. I am bit confused so I guess I did not ask the question for well. When I try to run I am getting the following errors: addToArray is defined
ReferenceError: addToArray is not defined at Context.<anonymous> (decoded.txt:27:12),

 adds numbers from num1 to num2 to an array,
 does not push the number 13 to an array
ReferenceError: addToArray is not defined at Context.<anonymous> (decoded.txt:36:12)

Comment: var addToArray = function(num1, num2) {
  var array = [];
  for (var i = num1; i <= num2; i++) {
    if(num1 > 12 && num2 < 14 ){
      continue;
    } 
    array.push(i);
  }
  return array;

};

Comment: You haven't defined num1 and num2. Javascript has no way to know what those numbers are. If you want num1 to equal the current Index then you will have to do that in the loop. Also, it looks like you want to set num2 to equal the total length of the array. I will update my answer below with this info.

Comment: Okay thanks! I think I got it figured out

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i = 0; i < sum.length; i++){
   if(sum[i] !== 13){
      sumOfArray += sum[i];
}
```

I'm assuming num1 = 0 and num2 = sum.length. You should check to see if the item at sum[i] doesn't equal 13 and add the item if it doesn't. it will skip over the number 13 if you do.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var numsToAddExceptThriteen = function(num1, num2) {
    var numsInArray = [];
    var totalSum    = 0;

    //make sure we start with the smaller number;
    if (num1 > num2) {
        var tempNum = num2;
        num2 = num1;
        num1 = tempNum;
    }

    //cycle through values and skip 13
    for ( var i = num1; i <= num2; i++ ) {
        if ( i !== 13 ) {
            numsInArray.push(i);
            totalSum += i
        }
    }
    //log both values
    console.log(numsInArray);
    console.log(totalSum);
};
numsToAddExceptThriteen(10, 80);
```

@Lkoprivica, I think what you will need is twofold. First you will need to define num1 and num2. I'm not sure how you are generating these numbers though, so cannot guess. As far as the loop, you could do something like so:

```
var num1, num2; //these should be populated with numbers from somewhere

for(var i = 0; i < sum.length; i++){
    if( (sum[i] === 13 && sum[i] > num1 && sum[i] < num2 ) || (sum[i] === 13 && sum[i] < num1 && sum[i] > num2 ) ){
        //we skip the else and move along if sum[i] is between num1 and num2 and if it equals 13
    } else {
        sumOfArray += sum[i];
    }
}
```